# Tegra3 -- High latency with hardware decoding

Tags: android, h.264, tegra, openmax

Hardware:Nexus 7

OS Version: Android 4.1.2

Problem:
I use OpenMAX IL to decode H.264 video stream(640x480). Between I give a raw H.264 frame and I receive a YUV frame, it is about 2~4 seconds. The YUV frame is correct.

Question:
Is it really need so much time? Or I have made wrong configurations?

Comment: do you use MediaCodec or any `openmax il` implementation ?

Comment: 2seconds is WAYYY more time than what an h/w encoder takes. So to answer your original question - **Yes. Looks like a mistake in your code/config**. In its current state, there not much more anyone can add to your question. Please share your code/config/setup details...